# Type for nodejs stream.Stream in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write typings for a [node module](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-stream-stack/blob/master/stream-stack.js) that includes a class that inherits from the nodejs `stream.Stream` class ... but I can't find that class in the typescript NodeJS module.  Where is it, and how should I handle the type of this `StreamStack` class, which seems to either be a `ReadableStream` or a `WritableStream` depending on context?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find all node types in [@types/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) package.
Just add this package to your project and that's it.

```
import { Stream } from 'stream'
```

Comment: I can't find `stream.Stream` in that package.  There's ReadableStream, WritableStream, and ReadWriteStream, which are interfaces, but I can't find any reference to a class called Stream.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v8/index.d.ts#L5271
Defined at line 5271.

Comment: Ah ... it's not in the `NodeJS` namespace, but can be imported by `import { Stream } from 'stream'`.  Thanks. :)

Comment: @Jules I've added your excellent suggestion to the answer.